# How to set date axis of the DateListPlot to follow the order of the data

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, time-series

I'm trying to show plots of weekly data from multiple periods each spanning June - April. The actual starting dates vary so the dates don't actually coincide but would like to stack them to compare the general profile of each period.

This is the sample data:

> data2019to20={{"6/2/19",3},{"6/9/19",0},{"6/16/19",3},{"6/23/19",2},{"6/30/19",3},{"7/7/19",9},{"7/14/19",2},{"7/21/19",9},{"7/28/19",9},{"8/4/19",6},{"8/11/19",8},{"8/18/19",19},{"8/25/19",11},{"9/1/19",23},{"9/8/19",13},{"9/15/19",23},{"9/22/19",22},{"9/29/19",14},{"10/6/19",24},{"10/13/19",16},{"10/20/19",12},{"10/27/19",3},{"11/3/19",7},{"11/10/19",10},{"11/17/19",13},{"11/24/19",12},{"12/1/19",12},{"12/8/19",6},{"12/15/19",9},{"12/22/19",9},{"12/29/19",7},{"1/5/20",40},{"1/12/20",100},{"1/19/20",20},{"1/26/20",20},{"2/2/20",25},{"2/9/20",0},{"2/16/20",3},{"2/23/20",4},{"3/1/20",4},{"3/8/20",1},{"3/15/20",0},{"3/22/20",2},{"3/29/20",0},{"4/5/20",0},{"4/12/20",2},{"4/19/20",3},{"4/26/20",0}};
>
> data2018to19={{"6/3/18",6},{"6/10/18",0},{"6/17/18",4},{"6/24/18",5},{"7/1/18",5},{"7/8/18",7},{"7/15/18",5},{"7/22/18",11},{"7/29/18",12},{"8/5/18",5},{"8/12/18",9},{"8/19/18",15},{"8/26/18",7},{"9/2/18",22},{"9/9/18",7},{"9/16/18",14},{"9/23/18",9},{"9/30/18",12},{"10/7/18",5},{"10/14/18",7},{"10/21/18",11},{"10/28/18",2},{"11/4/18",16},{"11/11/18",21},{"11/18/18",42},{"11/25/18",14},{"12/2/18",28},{"12/9/18",16},{"12/16/18",17},{"12/23/18",16},{"12/30/18",13},{"1/6/19",65},{"1/13/19",100},{"1/20/19",20},{"1/27/19",25},{"2/3/19",26},{"2/10/19",2},{"2/17/19",3},{"2/24/19",5},{"3/3/19",2},{"3/10/19",0},{"3/17/19",0},{"3/24/19",0},{"3/31/19",5},{"4/7/19",2},{"4/14/19",4},{"4/21/19",2},{"4/28/19",0}};

I tried:

```
DateListPlot[{Transpose[{StringDrop[data2019to20[[All, 1]], -3], data2019to20[[All, 2]]}], 
              Transpose[{StringDrop[data2018to19[[All, 1]], -3], data2018to19[[All, 2]]}]}, PlotRange -> All, DateFunction :> (DateList[{#, {"Month", "Day"}}] &)]
```

and I get:

[image: Plot of 2018-2019 & 2019-2020 data]

which starts in Jan and ends in Jan. How can I make it follow the order of the data - June to April? Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a quick helper function to aid the interpretation of your strings as dates:

```
ClearAll[do]
do[s_String] := DateObject[{s, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "YearShort"}}]
```

Then we use that function to interpret your strings as dates. While we are at it, we shift the 2018-2019 data by a year into the future, so it can be stacked on top of the 2019-20 data on the same timescale:

```
d1819 = {do[#1] + Quantity[1, "Years"], #2} & @@@ data2018to19;
d1920 = {do[#1], #2} & @@@ data2019to20;

DateListPlot[{d1819, d1920}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: stacked datelistplot with the right temporal range]

Comment: This works, Thanks a lot MarcoB!